# Problem with implementing linear advection using DG-method

Tags: discontinuous-galerkin

I am trying to implement a second order DG-method using a monomial basis and explicit Euler in time. I have written down some of the theory, which I present below:

**Theory**
Consider the linear advection function over $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ and a class of testfunctions $v\in C_0^1(\Omega)$
$$
 \int_\Omega\partial_tuvd x+a\int_\Omega\partial_xuvd x=0\;.\hspace{70pt}(1)
$$
Now, divide the computational domain $\Omega=\cup_{i=1}^N\Omega_i$ where $\Omega_i$ are disjoint, and let $h_i=x_{i+1}-x_{i}$ be the cell length. Integration by parts yield of $(1)$ yields
$$
 \int_{\Omega_i}\partial_tuv d x-a\int_{\Omega_i}uv' d x+\left[auv\right]_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}=0\;.\hspace{30pt}(2)
$$
The exact solution $u$ is now be approximated with $U_i$ over the cell $\Omega_i$ in a finite dimensional subset of $C_0^1(\Omega_i)$. Then the approximation of $u$ in cell $\Omega_i$ can be written
$$
 U_i=\sum_{j=0}^pc_{ij}\phi_j
$$
where $c_{ij}$ are time-depentent coefficients. In order to get a Galerkin method the basis functions and the testfunctions should be in the same space. For simplicity let this be the space of polynomials of degree $p$, i.e. $U_i,v\in\Pi_p$. For $v=\phi_k$, with $k=0,\ldots,p$, inserting into $(2)$ yields
$$
 \int_{\Omega_i}\partial_t\sum_{j=0}^pc_{ij}\phi_j\phi_k dx-a\int_{\Omega_i}\sum_{j=0}^pc_{ij}\phi_j\phi_k' d x+\left[a\sum_{j=0}^pc_{ij}\phi_j\phi_k\right]_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}=0\;.\hspace{10pt}(3)
$$
Let us define a suitable inner product on $\Omega_i$ following the $L^2$-space inner product definition
$$
 (u,v)=\int_{x_L}^{x_R}uvd x\;.
$$
Due to the smoothness properties of the testfunctions, the derivatives  and the sums can be moved out from under the integral sign, and we can rewrite $(3)$ as
$$
 \sum_{j=0}^p\left[\partial_tc_{ij}(\phi_j,\phi_k)-ac_{ij}(\phi_j,\phi_k')\right]+\left[a\sum_{j=0}^pc_{ij}\phi_j\phi_k\right]_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}=0\;.\hspace{30pt}(4)
$$
Let us now make some simplifications. First let $h=h_i$ for all cells, i.e. an equidistant grid. Secondly, restrict $p=1$ with the monomial basis
$$
 \phi_0=1,\qquad\phi_1=\frac{x-x_L}{x_R-x_L}
$$
giving
$$
 (\phi_0,\phi_0)=h,\quad(\phi_0,\phi_1)=\frac{h}{2},\quad(\phi_1,\phi_1)=\frac{h}{3},\\\quad(\phi_0,\phi_0')=0,\quad(\phi_0,\phi_1')=1,
\quad(\phi_1,\phi_1')=\frac{1}{2}\;.
$$

We are now ready to write this as a system
$$
 \partial_tMc_i-aM^fc_i+\left[M^s\overline{f}^N\right]_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}=0
$$
where $M=(m_{jk})$ where $m_{jk}=(\phi_j,\phi_k)$ and $M^f=(m^f_{jk})$ where $m^f_{jk}=(\phi_j,\phi_k')$ and
$$
 M^s=\begin{pmatrix}\phi_0(x)&0\\0&\phi_1(x)\end{pmatrix},\qquad\overline{f}^N=\begin{pmatrix}f^N(x)\\f^N(x)\end{pmatrix},\qquad c_i=\begin{pmatrix}c_{i,0}(t)\\c_{i,1}(t)\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some numerical flux function $f^N$. We will use the upwind flux, i.e.
$$
 f^N(U_{i-1},U_i)=aU_{i-1}(x_{i-1/2})
$$
The last step to complete the scheme is to apply the explicit Euler method in time. First rewrite  as
$$
 \partial_t c_i=aM^{-1}M^fc_i-M^{-1}\left[M^s\overline{f}^N\right]_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}
$$
We get
$$
 c_i^{n+1}=c_i^n+\Delta t\left(aM^{-1}M^fc_i^n-M^{-1}\left[M^s\overline{f}^N\right]_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}\right)
$$

**Implementaiton** The following is in Matlab

Assume we have an initial pulse $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ over $[-4,4]$. Then I extract the initial coefficient using
$$
u(x_L)=c_0\qquad u(x_R)=c_0+c_1
$$
i.e.

```
V =[1 0;-1 1];       
u=zeros(2, Ncells);
u(:)=f(x(:));
cini = V*u;
```

where $x$ is a matrix containing the the end points of each cell. Then I run the above, but the solution diverge quickly.

**Questions**
Does the theory seem okay, or are there any flaws? I can't figure out where it goes wrong. I can live with it if the implementation is a little off, but as long as I am not trying to program something that won't work it would be a relief.

Answer (score 1):

Just glancing through it quickly, it seems that you are using a second-order discretization in space with forward Euler in time.  That is unstable for any fixed CFL number (on fine enough grids).  You should use, e.g., a higher-order Runge-Kutta method.  It is possible to  check the stability by computing the eigenvalues of your semi-discretization and using method of lines stability analysis.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know that the central differences with explicit Euler in time is unconditionally unstable, but there are other methods like Lax-Wendroff, Beam-Warming that are second order and stable for some CFL condition. So, this must mean that the DG-method above is a central difference scheme essentially, but I don't find it very transparent. But, essentially changing to Heun's method would then be stable I assume. How can I check the stability via von Neumann analysis? I am used to FD-schemes and going to FV- or DG-schemes is not straight-forward.

Comment: One of your comments is correct; I have accordingly changed my answer.